# How to get fast ASP.Net application shutdown for restart/recycle on high traffic site?

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis, application-restart

I'm running a very high traffic site that gets a good 300+ requests/second (http://cooltext.com). A restart takes a good 90 seconds at least for it. So every time I post a new build it goes down for a minute or two. Long enough to trigger my monitoring services.

When I make a change that restarts the server, it appears that the restart stalls until all of the old requests on the old application pool (some of them very long running) complete. I can make the restart happen much faster by killing the old w3wp.exe instance manually.

Is there some way to force IIS to close all the connections right away and do a hard restart? Some setting in IIS or asp.net to control this?

Comment: Does it help running several working processes (a.k.a. web garden)?

Answer (score 1):

Just found the following that appears to be what I'm looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720127(v=vs.71).aspx

> Shutdown Time Limit is the equivalent application pool setting for the shutDownTimeout ASP.NET process model setting. It specifies the amount of time a worker process is given to shutdown gracefully. If the worker process does not shutdown in time amount specified, the ASP.NET ISAPI will end the worker process. Shutdown Time Limit is set to 90 seconds by default. You can specify a different time limit by changing the value in the spin box.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like this would hide the actual error. I thought that IIS would spawn a new worker process to take over _before_ the old process was terminated?